# Set CSS rule to specific letters in a word

Tags: css

I want to make three letters in a specific word bold or with any styling.
The word will be same all the time.
I can not change the html, just add CSS or JS.

Here's the example html:

```
<nav id="1f6b0b6d" class="m-nav-menu--holder m-nav-menu--horizontal"><ul id="menu-main-menu-2" class="menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom m-mega-menu--two menu-item-29651"><a href="#">amarteur</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom m-mega-menu--two menu-item-29652"><a href="#">cv</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

How to add CSS styling to for example "art" in "amarteur"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be achieved without modifying the HTML.

CSS only allows for `::first-letter` styling and `::first-word` styling.

Although, a JavaScript-based solution is possible: (this modifies the markup, though)

```js
const amarteurA = document.querySelector('.menu-item-29651');
amarteurA.innerHTML = amarteurA.innerHTML.replace('art', '<b>art</b>');
```

```html
<nav id="1f6b0b6d" class="m-nav-menu--holder m-nav-menu--horizontal"><ul id="menu-main-menu-2" class="menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom m-mega-menu--two menu-item-29651"><a href="#">amarteur</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom m-mega-menu--two menu-item-29652"><a href="#">cv</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

Comment: How to make it find all words "amarteur" on a page and add style/CSS to letters "art" in similar way as above?

Thanks!

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('art', '<b>art</b>');`

Comment: How to make this run on page load? Thanks!

Comment: Put this into a `<script></script>` and add it before `</body>`.

Comment: I only have access to header and footer to place scripts.

Comment: You could wrap this in ```window.addEventListener('load', () => { code });``` and put it anywhere.

Comment: Hmm I can't get it to work... like this?
`<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', () => { document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('art', '<span class="art">art</span>'); });
</script>`

Comment: And I only want to change "art" in "amateur" and not all existens of "art" on the page.